# Integrating a function around a segment with a finite incontinuity

Tags: calculus

It always seemed obvious for me that when integrating a function over an infinitesimal segment that contains a finite "jump", we receive $0$. I wonder how that can be justified mathematically. For the sake of the example, say we have $$f=\begin{cases}
f_{0} & x\in\left[-a,a\right]\\
0 & \text{elsewhere }
\end{cases}$$
Of course $f_0\neq0$ because otherwise it isn't interesting.
How does one show rigourously $$\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}fdx$$ vanishes?
I know the integral is invariant under changes of a finite number of values of $f$, but can that be applied here?

Comment: I don't undestand your question, the integral equals $\epsilon \cdot f_0$ just by standard computations. Then if you let $\epsilon \to 0$ the result will be 0.

Comment: My question is how have you evaluated the integral to be $\epsilon\cdot f_0$? $f$ is not equal to $f_0$ everywhere in $x\in[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ so substituting $f=f_0$ doesn't seem easily justifiable. I realize I'm asking a really simple question.

Comment: You can integrate between $[a-\epsilon,a]$ and then $[a,a+\epsilon]$ in the first interval you get $f=f_0$ in the second interval $f=0$. You can also proceed by saying that $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f \le 2\epsilon\cdot f_0$ because $f\le f_0$ then taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0 $ you get $0$